# Dropping values from the list

Tags: python

I got a multiple dataframe which looks like this:

```
A = [0,0,0,1,0,-1,2,-3,0,4,-4]
B = [0,0,0,1,-5,0,5,-6,0,4,-3,5,-6]
```

I wan to return a return where the first entry of the dataFrame is a **-ve** value where the last data is a **+ve** value.

Output

```
A = [-1,2,-3,4]
B = [-5,5,-6,4,-3,5]
```

How can I run a loop to look through all the dataframe? The length of the dataframe is different.

Comment: What should be the output in lists with multiple consecutive positive/negative values, e.g.,  `[-1,  2, 3, 4, -4, -3, -2, 5, 6]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

code:

```
a = [0,0,0,1,0,-1,2,-3,0,4,-4]
b = [0,0,0,1,-5,0,5,-6,0,4,-3,5,-6]

def arr(x):
    x[:] = (value for value in x if value != 0)
    while x[0] > 0:

        x.pop(0)

    while x[-1] < 0:
        x.pop()
    # print(x)
    return x

print(arr(a))
print(arr(b))
```

output:

```
[-1, 2, -3, 4]
[-5, 5, -6, 4, -3, 5]
```

you can also use `x.pop(0)` instead of `del x[0]`

Comment: What if my dataframe start with zero? Meaning df =[0,0,0,0,0,5,-5,3,-4,5,-6] and i just wan to return df = [-5,3,-4,5]

Comment: No, it does not work as expected. Your code fails with the OPs examples. Your code only examines the start and the end of the list and never deals with the values in the middle part.